# can't find module 'graphframes'

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, graphframes

When I input in command line :

> pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11

it will work well. 
But when I want to use ipython to launch my pyspark and use graphframes package, it doesn't work.

When I input in command line :

> PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11

the error is that:
can't find module 'graphframes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of Python 3 compatibility of the Spark packages [is a known bug](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/85) in `graphframes` 0.2.0 which has been resolved in 0.3.0.

```
--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.3.0-spark2.0-s_2.11
```